# Keeping index of array item in React constant after filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React component, which currently displays a list of technologies. The user can toggle which of these technologies are 'active' (i.e. selected) by clicking on them. They start as false, change to true, back to false and so on.

When the user does this, they get added to the overall technologies array and displayed on the frontend.

This is done through a 'toggleTechnology' function, which gets two properties passed in to it: item (the technology text) and index (where this item is in the array).

```
 const toggleTechnology = (item, index) => {

        console.log(item)
        console.log(index)

        if (technologies.includes(item)) {
            let filteredArray = technologies.filter((currentItem, currentIndex) => currentIndex !== index)

            setTechnologies(filteredArray)
        } else {
            setTechnologies(tech => [...tech, item])
        }

    }
```

The list of technologies is kept in a separate array, to be displayed dynamically on the frontend, like so:

```
const frontEndSklls = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Javascript', 'React', 'Unit tests', 'Vue.js']

{ frontEndSklls.map((item, index) => {
                                    return <span className={technologies.includes(item) ? "toggle-option active" : "toggle-option"} onClick={() => toggleTechnology(item, index)} key={index}>{item}</span>
                                }) }
```

My issue comes in when a user adds multiple skills and then removes some of them.

So for example, if they clicked on the following in this order, each item in the technologies array would have an index like this:

- 0: HTML
- 1: Unit tests
- 2: React
- 3: CSS

However, if they then clicked on 'React' to remove it, the array would go like this:

- 0: HTML
- 1: Unit tests
- 2: CSS

If they then click on CSS to remove it, I think because the new index of CSS is 2, it isn't removing the property. So what you need to do is click on another element first, say React again, and then CSS can be removed as the new array has CSS at index point 2.

So my question: is there a way for me to adjust my code so that the index remains the same for each of the options, even when you click on and off the elements?

The solution to me seems to be to turn each element in the array into an object, and assign a permanent index number and value to each element in the array - but this doesn't feel as clean as it could be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The main issue here is using the index as a key, which is an anti-pattern if the array being rendered isn't static (which, if you're filtering it, it isn't); see [this blog post](https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/) which is linked from [the React docs for keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) links to. With the list above, since the strings are unique, you could reliably use those as keys instead.

Comment: In `toggleTechnology` you would then do `technologies.filter((currentItem) => currentItem !== item)`

Comment: OP is mapping the original `frontEndSkills` array to populate JSX, and uses the filtered array `technologies` only to determine `className`s, so I'd say the actual rendered list in the UI is static. In this case, I don't think using the index as the key would break anything. But I agree, avoiding the usage of the index as key altogether would be good practice.

Comment: Never realised index was anti-pattern - you learn something new every day! Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different arrays in the component:

1. `frontEndSkills` - static - used to render *all* technologies in the UI with activated/deactivated status.
2. `technologies` - dynamic - the filtered array used to mark the active technologies in the UI as such.

The problem is that you're supplying the index of an item from the `frontEndSkills` array to be used in the `technologies` array, which is not always the same as the former.

@Subham Jain's answer also would work perfectly, but here is my shot at it, without the need for the index at all:

```
const toggleTechnology = (item) => {

  if (technologies.includes(item)) {
    let filteredArray = [...technologies].filter(currentItem => currentItem !== item)
    setTechnologies(filteredArray)
  } else {
    setTechnologies(tech => [...tech, item])
  }
}
```

Note: The suggestion to not use the index as a key from the other answers/comments here is sensible and highly recommended. Please consider that seriously. If you do have to use it for any reason at all, make sure that you understand *why* it is anti-pattern to do so.

Comment: Thanks Karthik! I'm using a slight adaptation here (not using spread operator and just flat state) and it works perfectly. As you say, the other solution works too, but I prefer not using index at all as think it's clear so accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that change 2 things.

Instead of using "index" for the "key" use "item".

Do not toggle the state based on the index. To achieve this you can modify the "toggletechnology" as below:-

```
const toggleTechnology = (item) => {
        if (technologies.includes(item)) {
            let indexOfItem = technologies.indexOf(item);
            let filteredArray = [...technologies].splice(indexOfItem,1);
            setTechnologies(filteredArray)
        } else {
            setTechnologies(tech => [...tech, item])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to not use `index` as key? And why do you suggest to use `item` as key? It's a string. If there are any duplicated entries, it may fail.

Comment: @kinduser Please refer to react docs from here:- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html It will give you a more detailed explanation of why not to use the index as a key. 

As for the item as key, I assumed that in the above scenario,frontEndSkills will contain distinct values. How often do you see a list which contains HTML twice?

Comment: Thanks Subham - this is a great response, but don't want to use splice (I personally prefer filter). You're right re. item as key too, the values shouldn't ever repeat so should be fine.

Comment: That's a matter of preference. 

Comment: Please stop spreading potentially harmful information, using index as a key is absolutely fine if only you are not re-ordering the list between renders. Using `item` is potentially harmful as well, you can't just assume that the entries won't be duplicated. It's just naive.

Comment: Please try to understand the fact that I never mentioned not using the index as a key ever. I suggested that as a good coding practice. Also, for the assumption, I think we can make that assumption in this use case. I never mentioned using item as a key in all use cases.